# Get credit card holders name on swipe Android (Cardflight)

Tags: android, credit-card

The question I'm posting is not completely related to technical.

I'm having a functionality where a Credit Card Reader will attach to audio jack of device and capture data upon swipe and make transaction. For this I'm using CardFlight SDK and their device [CardFlight docs](https://cardflight.com/docs)

I'm able to get all details like (Card Number, Expiry date, CVV) expect card holders name. Method which SDK is providing to get name `card.getName()` (card is Card class instance which will receive on Swipe successful) always returns `null`. I get in touch with CardFlight technical support they said card holders name is encrypted be received after transaction is success. Reply mail from card flight customer is below, This is also not working for me.

> Hi, Can you try to call get name after the card is being charged?
>   Usually the name is encrypted and the getName method is working only
>   when the charge is returned from the server.
>
> Hope that helps.

I replied back to CardFlight customer care that it is not working.

Code snippet on swipe

```
@Override
public void readerCardResponse(Card card) {
     //METHOD WILL INVOKE ON CARD SWIPE SUCCESSFUL
     //CODE TO MAKE PAYMENT 
}

@Override
public void transactionSuccessful(Charge charge) {
    //METHOD INVOKED ON PAYMENT SUCCESSFUL
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the problem and CardFlight support response is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

We could replicate this issue and it has now been fixed.
Please pull the latest version of the SDK and let me know if the problem persists

Comment: Thanks Elie, I have seen your library have updated and integrated, working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone facing this problem can update cardflight latest library from below link
https://github.com/CardFlight/android-demo

@Rishabh you can now directly get cardholders name by "card" instance.